How to run useEffect's cleanup function when a suspended component unmounts?
When a suspended component unmounts, useEffect's cleanup function doesn't run. This leads to memory leaks, unused event handlers, etc. This makes useEffect unintuitive to use, since we'd typically assume the cleanup function always runs when the component unmounts.
E.g. something like this:
function Foo() {
  const [isSuspended, setIsSuspended] = useState(false);

  if (isSuspended) {
    throw ...
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(...);

    return () => {
      // This doesn't run if unmounted while suspended
      window.removeEventListener(...);
    };
  }, []);

  return <button onClick={() => setIsSuspended(true)} />
}

Is there a good way to make the useEffect cleanup function run if the component was suspended before unmounting?

suspend or suspense

can you share your a code snippet of this issue?

Seems to work: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/gallant-matsumoto-2j3xgq?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A24%2C11 ?

It is known issue,  with React Suspense,  you can use a combination of react , useRef and useLayoutEffect hooks to ensure that cleanup is performed when the component is unmounted, even if it is suspended.

@AnilSingha do you have an example? I couldn't find any

function Foo() {
  const [isSuspended, setIsSuspended] = useState(false);
  const isMounted = useRef(true);

  // This will run the cleanup when the component unmounts
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
   window.addEventListener(...);
    return () => {
      // This cleanup will run only if the component is still mounted
      if (isMounted.current) {
        window.removeEventListener(...);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  if (isSuspended) {
   throw ...
  }

  return <button onClick={() => setIsSuspended(true)} />;
}

I am using your sample, you can refer like this.

I guess this might work in the specific example, but in a large realistic web app, moving the suspense throw to after all the useEffects is infeasible

As per your sample, above code you can refer,  One approach for large scale  is to manually manage state to track whether the component should perform side effects. This way, you can ensure that cleanup functions are called correctly, regardless of Suspense. @LeoJiang
